# Peekdata returns only one channel

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab stereo audio input ala:

```
aud=analoginput('winsound',0);
addchannel(aud,1:2)
```

When I'm done running this and ask for

```
aud_data=getdata(aud);
```

I get an array showing all the data from both channels. I have verified that this data is, in fact, the valid stereo signal that I want.

However, if I run

```
aud_peek=peekdata(aud,some_number_of_samples);
```

whilst data is being collected, I only seem to get one channel's worth of data, though MathWorks [says I should get two](http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/peekdata.html).

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

I am using Matlab 7.

Comment: Hmm the manual is not specific about the behaviour. Maybe you need to run "peekdata" on both channels (lefts & right) separately (?).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
`aud_peek=peekdata(aud,some_number_of_samples,'native');`
or 
`aud_peek=peekdata(aud,some_number_of_samples,'double');`